# Problems with elements order in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Several days ago I started to learn Java EE and web development *(firstly: Tomcat, Servlets, JSP)*.

So now I have this JSP page code. 
As you can see, the header `Hello World with JSP` stay before `<% ... %>` block.:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>

<html>
<body>
<h1 align=”center”>Hello World with JSP</h1>
<br>
<%
    List styles = (List)request.getAttribute("styles");
    for(Object style: styles){
    response.getWriter().println("<br>try: " + style);
    }
%>

</body>
</html>
```

But in result web page result from `<% ... %>` stay before the `Hello World with JSP` header. Why?

[image: screenshot]

P.S. Sorry for terminology but I'm really new in web development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSPs use an implicit `JspWriter` instance called `out` to write to the output stream. It's not exactly the same as the `PrintWriter` instance you receive from `response.getWriter()` as it does some additional buffering before it actually writes to the stream.

When you directly print to `PrintWriter` you've basically written to the stream before the `JspWriter` buffer was flushed and hence your `List` gets printed before the "Hello World" HTML.

What you need instead is to use the implicit `JspWriter` instance `out` as

```
<%
    List styles = (List)request.getAttribute("styles");
    for(Object style: styles){
        out.println("<br>try: " + style);
    }
%>
```

By the way, *scriptlets* `<% %>` in JSPs are deprecated now. Please, look into JSP EL and JSTL tags.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use out.println instead of response.getWriter().println. See [How to output HTML from JSP <%! … %> block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138999/how-to-output-html-from-jsp-block)

Answer (score 2):

A JSP is compiled to a Java servlet. When you executed the following scriplet code

```
response.getWriter().println(...);
```

you are getting the `HttpServletResponse`'s `PrintWriter` which writes directly to the `OutputStream`, acting before any HTML (from the jsp) is written. Take this example

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<%
    response.getWriter().println("hellllooooooooo"); // using response.getWriter().println()
%>
the time is now
<h1 align=”center”>Hello World with JSP</h1>
<br>
<%
    List styles = (List)request.getAttribute("styles");
    for(Object style: styles){
        out.println("<br>try: " + style); // using out.println()
    }
%>

</body>
</html>
```

The response content you will receive is

```
hellllooooooooo



<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

the time is now
<h1 align=”center”>Hello World with JSP</h1>
<br>
<br>try: asdaS
<br>try: asdasdasda


</body>
</html>
```

Notice the `hellllooooooooo` is printed before anything. `JSP`s give you a `out` variable that is of type `JspWriter` which allows you to output in the expected order. See the above example for writing the elements from the request attribute `styles`.

**IMPORTANT** This is one of the reasons that scriplets are not recommended. Consider using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) instead.