# Where do I write jspInit()

Tags: jsp, web-applications

I must implement the `jspInit()` method in order to read a text file and print the content on the web page. But I have no idea where to put it.
I've tried before `<DOCTYPE>`, between others jsp imports but I was not able to access to objects like `out`.

```
<%@page import="java.io.FileReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
<%@page import="java.io.IOException"%>
<%@page import="java.io.FileWriter"%>
<%@page import="java.io.PrintWriter"%>
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="ML.*"%>
<%! 
    public void jspInit() throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/ambra/a.txt"));
        String s = br.readLine();        
        while(s != null){

        }
    }
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Print here the content of the text file -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I have no idea where to put it

You can put it any where but  it is typically declared as JSP declarations.

```
<%! public void jspInit() {   
   //your code
 }  
%> 
<html>
...
</html>
```

> but I was not able to access to objects like out

**out** is an implicit object and implicit objects are the local variables inside the **_jspService** method, so implicit objects can be available only in _jspService() method and not within jspInit() or jspDestroy().**From jspInit() and jspDestroy() you can not access any implicit objects.**

Comment: Thank you. So, what if I have to print on the web page something? Like "this is a jspInit method"? I tried getting the writter with `response.getEritter()` but didn't work. Any idea ?

Comment: response is also an implicit object. So u can not do that. Go through this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138999/how-to-output-html-from-jsp-block

Comment: But... `jspInit()` is not called by default, isn't it? I had to call it explicitly. By the way I solved it : `<%!
    public void jspInit(javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter o) throws IOException{
        o.println("Yupiiii");
        }
%>`

and then in the scriptlet I called it: `<%
            jspInit(out); %>`

Is it ok?

Comment: No,it is not ok. although the name of ur method is jspInit but it is not the life cycle method of jsp. the signature of the jsp life cycle method is :public void jspInit(){}.Do one thing, try to view the content of the generated .class file. It will clear ur confusion.

Comment: My `classes` directory is empty. So, you're saying I should not pass any parameter to `jspInit` nor throw any exceptions, right? But how am I supposed to communicate with my page? I cannot find any exemple of this on line. Am I googling the wrong thing? "jspInit example"

Comment: It should be empty, if u have not created any java classes.If u have only jsp file then after deployment it will be generated but not inside the classes folder.r u running it from eclipse? If yes, then check - ur workspace 's".metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\" folder.