# muliple annotations found at this line in jsp

Tags: jsp

I working in a program in jsp, trying myself learning a jsp.

so i doing a quiz program, where questions are get from the database tables. So here is the code of the quiz page, where questions are posted.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <%@ include file="_header.jsp"%>

    <center>QUIZ PROGRAM</center>

    <br />

    <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>

    <%
        //print the question and answer

        int questionaire = 1;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quiz", "root", "");
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id = ?");
        pst.setInt(1, questionaire);

        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

        int questionId;
        String questionp;

        if (rs.next()) {
            questionId = rs.getInt("id");
            String questionp = rs.getString("question");
            //String option1 = rs.getString("option1");
            //String option2 = rs.getString("option2");
            //String right = rs.getString("right");
            questionaire++;
        }
        //get the answer and check
        //String question1 = "asd";
    %>

    <center>
        <form method="post" action="quiz.jsp">
            <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" align="center">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2"><% out.println(questionp); %></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="question"
                            value="value1">Yes</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="question"
                            value="value2">No</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit"
                            value="Next" onClick="next();" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </center>



</body>
</html>
```

In the above code, i am getting a error in this line stating that,

```
String questionp = rs.getString("question");
```

muliple annotations found at this line

[image]

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem you are facing? Please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to properly state your problem.

Comment: `<% out.println("questionp"); %>` is printing the value `questionp` not the variable. Use `<% out.println(questionp); %>` or `<%= questionp %>` (I think). But like greenPadawan said, please see [ask] and provide a [mcve] next time. Just by writing it, you will find your problem. I would add that you should quickly learn how to use `Servlets` and `Jstl` to write JSP correctly ;)

Comment: @greenPadawn sorry about, i am not explaining my issue i faced, now i have i have edited the question, explaining my problem, still it shows errors.

Comment: @AxelH thanks, i have updated my question, also as you said i have changed the code by removing double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Your output is wrong

```
<% out.println("questionp"); %>
```

This will not print the value you recover but the text "questionp".

You need to output the variable with

```
<% out.println(questionp); %>
```

Or

```
<%= questionp %>
```

---

For more solution, [see the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138999/how-to-output-html-from-jsp-block)

EDIT :

For your edit, `multiple annontaion` means that you already declare a variable with this name. Here, you declare `questionp` twice.

```
String questionp;
if (rs.next()) {
    String questionp = rs.getString("question");
```

Remove the type :

```
String questionp = null;
if (rs.next()) {
    questionp = rs.getString("question");
```

Comment: i am getting error in the line, <% out.println(questionp); %> the local variable questionp may not have been initialized

Comment: @javailike This is because I didn't check ... since you don't have an `else`, the String might never been initialized. So init the value with a default or to null. (See edited code) This is some basic Java, don't learn to quickly JSP if you don't know Java.

Comment: what about int, int questionId = null; this shows me error

Comment: Again, this is basic Java, don't rush ... `int` is a primitive type, this can't be null. But you can always set it to an impossible value, -1 if you only have positive.

Comment: Thanks its worked out, but this line <%= questionp %> shows error in eclipse ide

Comment: @javailike It should not here is a quick line `<% String s = null;%><%= s %>`.. but if Eclipse won't let you use this, then use your first style (with the correction).