# How to get return value from javascript through JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, dom-events, jsp-tags

```js
function testing(){
    var e = document.getElementById("selectBranchId");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; 
    return strUser;
}

function test(){
    var resultValue = testing();
    alert(resultValue);
}
```

How can I get the value of `resultValue` in JSP? I tried using `request.setAttribute` but I am getting error variable `resultValue` can't be resolved. What can be the solution?

Comment: JS code doesn't start running until after JSP has finished. Your client side JS needs to send a request to the server using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

As JavaScript runs on the client side and JSP/Scriptlet is running on the server-side.

So if you want to access any of your JavaScript variable in JSP/Java/Server Side, then either

1. Submit it as a Hidden form field
2. or Pass it via Ajax Request

Answer (score 0):

The variable doesn't exist beforehand in the JspWriter. Consider your javascript in two categories; before the page is written and after.

```
<html>
        <head/>
        <body>
                <%!
                        function testing(){
                                var e = document.getElementById("selectBranchId");
                                var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; 
                                return strUser;

                        }
                %>
                <% testing(); %>
        </body>
</html>
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/139018/7355848) for more information.