# Java, JSP - How to pass a String describing an HTML Tag via session set attribute into page

Tags: java, html, jsp, httpsession, setattribute

I set a session attribute from controller like this.:

```
String someHtmlTag = "<a href='something'><img src='somewhere'></img></a>";
session.setAttribute("someHtmlTag", someHtmlTag );
```

Then on JSP:

```
<div>
    ${someHtmlTag}
</div>
```

But on the generated HTML, it only prints the string describing the tag.

How do I print the expected hyperlink image instead?

That HTML is dynamic, and comes from database. That's why that's not hardcoded on JSP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10996495/1927832

Comment: Recommending scriptlets?  That's horrible.  Wrong.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code. It works on my machine. Did you look at the source code that your server sent to your browser? Please show us that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not do this.

Get the bits that change out of the database, but markup belongs in the JSP.  Pass the changing bits into the JSP and let it render markup.

The recommendation to use scriptlets is wrong in every way.

You can make an AJAX call and add markup into the `<div>`.  Scriptlets are a 1990s technology that should never, ever be used.